# CMU Sphinx Compatible Dictionaries

Tags: speech-to-text, cmusphinx

When running CMU Sphinx against a provided wav file, I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Missing HMM for unit P with lc=R rc=ER0
19:06:29.696 SEVERE lexTreeLinguist    Bad HMM Unit: EH1
Aug 16, 2016 7:06:29 PM edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree addPronunciation
SEVERE: Missing HMM for unit N with lc=EH1 rc=Z
19:06:29.697 SEVERE lexTreeLinguist    Bad HMM Unit: OW0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMNode.getBaseUnit(HMMTree.java:494)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMNode.<init>(HMMTree.java:472)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.Node.addSuccessor(HMMTree.java:164)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree$EntryPoint.createEntryPointMap(HMMTree.java:1154)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree$EntryPointTable.createEntryPointMaps(HMMTree.java:1012)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree.compile(HMMTree.java:784)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.HMMTree.<init>(HMMTree.java:706)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.LexTreeLinguist.generateHmmTree(LexTreeLinguist.java:428)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.LexTreeLinguist.compileGrammar(LexTreeLinguist.java:416)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.lextree.LexTreeLinguist.allocate(LexTreeLinguist.java:335)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:243)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.allocate(AbstractDecoder.java:103)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:164)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer.startRecognition(StreamSpeechRecognizer.java:52)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer.startRecognition(StreamSpeechRecognizer.java:39)
```

I am using [the CMUDict on Github](https://github.com/cmusphinx/cmudict) and a language model [on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/)

When googlin' this error, people hint that there is mis-match between the acoustic model and the dictionary.  However, I can't find any documentation on which models / dictionaries are compatible.  The CMU site does not provide any guidance. I've attempted several pairings, but I would be grateful for direct guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary compatible with the model is already included in distribution and [source tree](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/tree/master/sphinx4-data/src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us).

The dictionary in github project has stress marks in phonemes which must be removed with the script before using in the decoder.

Comment: That dictionary appears to be the smaller dictionary.  The one on github is much larger.  Is there a larger dictionary available?  Also, the language model in the source tree is considerably smaller.

Comment: The language model is exactly the same, the dictionary is the same too, they were synced two months ago.